# exception occur with the future builder and binding.dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-getx

> Exception has occurred.
> _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 146 pos 12: '_debugInitializedType == null': is not true.)

it is throwing this error but i just change the thing to another that i got ans from stack overflow itself if any code needed then just ans on code need iwill provide every code indeed i am currently using getx and state management and i have also provided one animation page on the starting maybe its the tests that cause this exception i am putting the code for main.dart and the tests i performed in the firebase failure cfile

main.dart

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)
      .then((value) => Get.put(AuthenticationReporsitory()));
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      // home: AppBar(
      //   title: Text("LearningNew"),
      //   leading: Icon(Icons.ondemand_video),
      // ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: TAppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: TAppTheme.darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      defaultTransition: Transition.leftToRightWithFade,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      home: WelcomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

signupandemailfailure.dart

```
class SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure {
  final String message;

  const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
      [this.message = "An Unknown Error occured."]);

  factory SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure.code(String code) {
    switch (code) {
      case 'weak-password':
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
            'Please enter a stronger password');
      case 'invalid-email':
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
            'Enmail is not  valid or badly formatted ');
      case 'email-already-in-use':
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
            'An account already exists for that email');
      case 'operation-not-allowed':
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
            'Operation not allowed. Please contact the support');
      case 'user-disabled':
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure(
            'This user has been disabled. Please contact the support for help');
      default:
        return const SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure();
    }
  }
}
```

if anyone here is kind to just try to solve this problem thanks to them <3

Comment: Dont about getx,but you are trying to use ` Get.put(AuthenticationReporsitory()))` before  `GetMaterialApp(`